# How do I invert this timer in BGE to make it count-down?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks, properties, text-object

This is from an answer I received here: [timer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36404/timers-and-animation-frame-rate)

> I suggest to avoid this method to measure time. The BGE will try to
>   keep the given frame rate as much as possible, but there is no
>   guaranty.
>
> I recommend to use a timer property. It counts the seconds. I think
>   that is what you really want.
>
> Then you have several ways to show the time. I think you want to
>   format it to minutes:seconds. You can use this little script
>   `timeToText`:

```
 import bge 
 from datetime import datetime

 textObject = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner 
 time = datetime.fromtimestamp(textObject["time"]) 
 textObject.text = '{:%M:%S}'.format(time)
```

> It expects a property time to provide the seconds and should be
>   applied to an text object.
>
> [image]
>
> You can indeed refresh the display each 60 frames. But you will not
>   know when the seconds changed. Therefore I suggest to run it
>   constantly.
>
> Hint: If you want to show microseconds too, use this format:
>   `{:%M:%S.%f}`

This works. But the timer in bge counts upwards. What if I want it to count let's say from 30 minutes downwards?

How can I "invert" the timer?
I guess I can assign the original value 30 to the property time but how do I achieve the countdown logic afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply negate the **time property** (-1800 seconds) and parameter of `datetime.fromtimestamp(`**-**`textObject["time"])`:

[image]

```
import bge 
from datetime import datetime

textObject = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
if textObject["time"] < 0:
    time = datetime.fromtimestamp(-textObject["time"])
    textObject.text = '{:%M:%S}'.format(time)
```