# property timer value

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

Coming back to this thread: [countdown timer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36474/how-do-i-invert-this-timer-in-bge-to-make-it-count-down)

I want to check the time property and set a new scene when it reaches 0.

What should I put in the Value box of a Property-equal sensor to check for when the timer reaches 0? I tried 0, 00:00, some other formats although I think I can't really put expressions there and none of them worked.

Maybe this `textObject.text = '{:%M:%S}'.format(time)` is something that I can't play with in the Value box of the Property and I need to go through python, but I wonder if there is a simple logic brick solution.

These are the logic bricks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong after I printed the property.

The values of the property are float with tons of decimals, meaning it could end up to be 0.00000000002 and never reach 0.

So you can either round the number but it would round it when it gets near -0.5.

So I just changed the equal-property to be a greater-than-property and set its value to be -0.1.

So now since it is a countdown timer, when the timer reaches second 1 it sets my new scene.

Answer (score 1):

As the timer property provides a float value, you need to check if the value is "equal or above zero". Since Blender 2.74 the property sensor has according modes. If you use an older version, you can use the interval mode

The value to check against is -> 0 or 0.0 it does not matter which one.

Comment: I edited the question and added an image. It does not work with either 0 or 0.0 . What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my statement. It should be "zero or above" (both conditions needs to be checked at the same time)