# Timer with uncapped frame rate

Tags: python, game-engine

I have been struggling a ton to get a basic time trial type timer that includes milliseconds.

The kicker is, I REALLY want to have my frame rate uncapped. With that in mind, this solution I found counts WAY too fast (it counts approx 30 seconds every actual second):  [Timers and animation frame rate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36404/timers-and-animation-frame-rate)

I'm thinking there may be something to using datetime, but I can't figure it out. If I could just somehow start a timer at 0, then add to it the time between the previous and current frame, I'd be golden. I just can't figure out how to do that.

EDIT: I think I am close with bge.logic.getRealTime()   ...I just can't display it in the text object for some reason. I get "error return without exception set". It displays in the console just fine if I print it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I've answered my own question. Here's a quick script for anyone who finds this later down the road. Just attach this to a text property and you should be good.

```
import bge 
from datetime import datetime

textObject = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner 
timePassed = bge.logic.getRealTime()
timePassed = str(round(timePassed,2))
textObject.text = timePassed
```